# Send JavaScript in an HTTP post request

Tags: javascript, post, request

Let's say I have foo.html and there is a text-field where I submit text that is shown afterwards on the site. It is possible to write JavaScript in this text-field. For example `<script>alert(1)</script>` and `<script>alert(1);</script>` works.

What I want to do is to send a JavaScript as message per post request to foo.html. The form has a text-area and its name is "textfield". My JavaScript code which should send another script code looks as follows:

```
var r = new XMLHttpRequest();
var script_code = "<script>alert(1)<\/script>";
url = "foo.html";
r.open("POST", url, false);
var content = "textfield=".concat(script_code);
r.send(content);
```

That works fine. But I am confused because:

```
var r = new XMLHttpRequest();
var script_code = "<script>alert(1);<\/script>";
url = "foo.html";
r.open("POST", url, false);
var content = "textfield=".concat(script_code);
r.send(content);
```

or

```
var r = new XMLHttpRequest();
var script_code = "<script>alert(1);\n alert(2);<\/script>";
url = "foo.html";
r.open("POST", url, false);
var content = "textfield=".concat(script_code);
r.send(content);
```

don't work. If I remove the semicolons it works again:

```
var r = new XMLHttpRequest();
var script_code = "<script>alert(1);\n alert(2);<\/script>";
script_code = script_code.replace(/;/g,"");
url = "foo.html";
r.open("POST", url, false);
var content = "textfield=".concat(script_code);
r.send(content);
```

But I have a much larger script saved as a string that I want to send to foo.html but it doesn't work. It doesn't work as well if I remove all semicolons. That's why my questions is:
What does a "script as a string" has to look like so that this works?

EDIT:
@Keith Let's say I want to try the following:

```
<script id=script_id> 
//TODO: What do I have to write here to decode?
var r = new XMLHttpRequest();
alert(1);
alert(2);
var script_code = document.getElementById("script_id").innerHTML;
var sub_string_begin='<script>';
var sub_string_end="<\/script>";
script_code = sub_string_begin.concat(script_code, sub_string_end);

url = "foo.html";
r.open("POST", url, false);
var content = "textfield=".concat(script_code);
content = encodeURIComponent(content);
r.send(content);
</script>
```

So I want to send the script itself. How do I decode it then?

Comment: Shouldn't `<script>alert(1);<\/script>` be `<script>alert(1);</script>` and `<script>alert(1);\n alert(2);<\/script>` be `<script>alert(1); alert(2);</script>`?

Comment: @JustinJmnz  It's basically string escaping and would be fine here, although the `\/` is a bit pointless it will still work, no need to escape `/`, but the `\n` for newline does want escaping.

Comment: @Keith: So do I have to escape the string like
`script_code = escape(script_code)`?

Comment: @Cybergy I was replying to JustinJmnz, and was pointing out your string escaping is fine. Looking at how your sending it you might want -> `encodeURIComponent("<script>alert(1);\n alert(2);</script>");` and then the receiving end `decodeURIComponent`

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on how the post request is handled by 'foo.html'.

Very likely the post request is sanitised there.